# JAXB how to remove anything from JDefinedClass

Tags: jaxb

i am using jaxb to generate code from an xsd.

The generated code contains a lot of annotations; for classes and fields.

I am trying to use `com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Plugin` to modify the generated code.

In the plugin `run()` method we are given an `Outline` class from which we can get `ClassOutline`. `ClassOutline` has an `JDefinedClass` final member which has the info about actual class which will be generated.

If i want to add anything, there are apis in `JDefinedClass` which can be used. But if i want to remove something, there is no way.

e.g. i cannot clear annotations, because the `JDefinedClass.annotations()` method returns an `UnmodifiableCollection`. so i cannot clear it or remove anything from it.

i tried to create another `JDefinedClass` by invoking the `_class` method but the `ClassOutline.implClass` variable is final, so i cannot set it.

how to get a `JDefinedClass` which does not have any annotations?

is there another phase of code generation which i can trap into to really control the generation of `JDefinedClass`?

Comment: Short answer: you'll need to remove things from the model, not from the code model. Long answer follows.

Comment: i see there is a `postProcessModel` method, with `Model` as input. i am seeing how can this `Model` can be manipulated to remove annotations

Comment: i see that `BeanGenerator` does not do any checks before invoking `implClass.annotate2`. there is no way to stop its invocations

Comment: i finally did it. removed each `JDefinedClass` from the `_package`. added new `JDefinedClass` with the same name, and copied `implements`, `extends`, `fileds`, `methods`, `javadoc` etc from original `JDefinedClass`. a bit tedious but couldn't find anything else to do.

Answer (score 1):

The code model is, indeed mostly "write only". But, speaking of annotations, you have probably missed the methods like `com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass.removeAnnotation(JAnnotationUse)` and `com.sun.codemodel.JMethod.removeAnnotation(JAnnotationUse)` (implemented from `com.sun.codemodel.JAnnotatable.removeAnnotation(JAnnotationUse)`).

So they're there. You can remove annotations with the normal CodeModel API.

As I can see, you can also remove fields and methods from classes. So what exactly are you missing?

Comment: actually in my `jdk1.7.0_55\lib\tools.jar` , the `JDefinedClass` and `JMethod` does not have any method called `removeAnnotation`. yes, there is a `removeField` in `JDefinedClass`

Comment: @weima Don't use JDK-internal XJC. I checked some more-or-less actual JAXB RI.

Comment: you mean i should install jaxb-ri and use its xjc. which is the distribution which provided JAXB RI implementation? can you suggest. i could not find any jaxb-ri impl which even contains `JDefinedClass`. i saw `com.sun.xml.bind » jaxb-impl`

Comment: also my boss tells me not to use vendor specific apis. isnt `com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Plugin` vendor specific? i could not find any other `Plugin` class

Comment: using jaxb-ri from here instead "https://jaxb.java.net/downloads/ri/" version 2.2.11\

Comment: Just use the right dependencies. See this QA, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413431/which-artifacts-should-i-use-for-jaxb-ri-in-my-maven-project
It does not matter, where you get them. I'm using Maven and get dependencies from the central Maven repository which also contains JAXB RI: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/

Comment: Well, XJC plugin **is** vendor specific. So, take it or leave it, there is nothing to discuss.

Comment: this version has `jDefinedClass.removeAnnotation(JAnnotationUse)`

Answer (score 0):

JDefinedClass.annotations() It return an unmodifiable collection object and you cannot modify them.

So work around for this, you can restrict annotation addition/deletion at class and field level before building JCodeModel.

You need to create a custom Jackson2Annotator class which extends Jackson2Annotator and override their methods according to your requirement.

Following are few methods which are being used for specific type of annotation property:

1. propertyOrder(OTB JsonPropertyOrder)
2. propertyInclusion(OTB JsonInclude)
3. propertyField(can be used for custom defined annotation at field level)

More you can discover by looking Jackson2Annotator class what fit into your need.