# JXB How to use different strategies of code generation

Tags: jaxb

usually, JAXB is used to generate code from an xsd, which generates java classes for xsd `complexType` with annotations to convert it to xml and vice-versa.

I am trying to achieve something different. I want, to generate a data mapper class for each such xsd element. The mapper will map each field of the generated class with values from another datatype (say from database, or other stream)

so i need to: for every user-defined datatype in xsd, add a method in a `DataMapper` class `map-<XSD-ComplexDataType-Class>()` and generate method body.

to achieve this, i think it is not possible to generate this class in a Plugin extending `com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Plugin` as in the `run` method, i wont be able to create a new `JDefinedClass`

is there any way to add a hook method before `Model` invokes `Plugins` ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can do. In [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247730/what-is-the-role-of-classoutline-jclass-cclass-in-codemodel/9404341) I specificaly meant these:

- In a plugin you can write and set your own `com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.FieldRendererFactory`. Field renderers generate a `FieldOutline`s from `CPropertyInfo`s. This is a step between the model and the outline. So if you want different code generated out of the model, consider implementing your own `FieldRendererFactory`. You can register a `FieldRendererFactory` via XJC plugin (see `Options.setFieldRendererFactory(...)`).
- On the class level, you can write your own `com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator` and use it for code generation.
- You can just use `model` and generate the code completely on your own. I do this in Jsonix when I produce JavaScript mappings for XML<->JSON.

As for your specific task, I would actually just postprocess the code model in the `run` method of your plugin. You have everything there - the `model`, the `outline` and also the code model (see `outline.getCodeModel()`). And you can definitely create your `JDefinedClass`es there, the code model exists already.

Comment: yes, i followed like you told at the end, i defined my own `JDefinedClass` and adding methods to it. it is in very initial stages. thanks!